# Sending input to a windows application from outside

Tags: windows, powershell, gnu-screen, conemu

In Linux, I can start a program in a GNU screen session and then send input to it from outside using screen's `stuff` command, which sends characters exactly as if I had typed them in the program. I'm new to developing in Windows and I was wondering if a similar feature exists in Windows?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with ConEmu?

Comment: That's the terminal I'm using which seems to be quite feature rich. I was hoping maybe ConEmu somehow supports this?

Comment: The standard automation infrastructure in Windows is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). You can check if any given application exposes the required interfaces using the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool.

Comment: http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Print

Answer (score 1):

If you won't use 3rd party apps like
**AutoIT** or
**AutoHotKey** there are
[vbscript sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) and rather complex
Windows API SendMessage methods.

The here easiest seems to be [Converting the Windows Script Host SendKeys Method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx) (to powershell):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Test.ps1 - Notepad")

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F1}")
```

To evalute the window title for `AppActivate` you could use :

```
Get-Process|Where{$_.Mainwindowtitle}|select processName,Mainwindowtitle
```

Comment: Thanks, I now have a few things to try.